# How to execute a method outside of a thread in which a dependent parameter is in

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Assume a generic method, i.e. `sayHello(a)`, takes argument `str` as a formal parameter.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String str = "Hello World";
        sayHello(str);
    }           
}).start();
```

I need to execute `sayHello(str)` outside of this thread (or more importantly, inside the main thread), however `String str = "Hello World";` must be executed within this new thread. So, how would I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Why did you tag android, do you want to call sayHello in a new thread, outside of the UI thread..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

  @Override
  public void run() {
      final String str = "Hello World";

      runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
      {
          public void run()
          {
              sayHello(str);
          }
      });
  }

}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `str` in main Thread and assign the value in the new Thread then you can call `sayHello` method.

Comment: Sorry, but why it must be final?

Comment: If I declare str in main Thread and assign value in the new Thread, then str becomes "" (null) as the sayHello(str) method is executed before the new Thread and in this case str = "".

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to achieve exactly. Why do you want to call SayHello before new Thread?

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`.

From JDK 6 api documentation.

```
 interface ArchiveSearcher { String search(String target); }
 class App {
   ExecutorService executor = ...
   ArchiveSearcher searcher = ...
   void showSearch(final String target) throws InterruptedException {
     Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
         public String call() { return searcher.search(target); }
     });
     displayOtherThings(); // do other things while searching
     try {
       displayText(future.get()); // use future
     } catch (ExecutionException ex) { cleanup(); return; }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check answers for this similar question "[how to wait for Android runOnUiThread to be finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996885/how-to-wait-for-android-runonuithread-to-be-finished/9893835#9893835)". It contains an implementation of BlockingOnUIRunnable class that should solve your problem. It will also run your sayHello() function synchronously.