# Do something in UI thread from another thread and wait for completion

Tags: android

My code was invoked from `AsyncTask.doInBackground()`, but I need to use an object whose methods should be called from the UI thread.

I gues, I can do this with Handler, but there's no `send()` method, only `post()` method that doesn't wait.

```
public class Synchronizer implements PlayerInterface {

    private final PiterFMPlayer playerInstance = new PiterFMPlayer();
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void open(final String channelId, final String trackTime) {
        handler.send(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playerInstance.open(channelId, trackTime);
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm even thinking now of lock/notify:

```
public class Synchronizer implements PlayerInterface {

    private final PiterFMPlayer playerInstance = new PiterFMPlayer();

    @Override
    public void open(final String channelId, final String trackTime) {
        new MySender() {
            @Override
            public void run2() {
                playerInstance.open(channelId, trackTime);
            }
        };
    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private RuntimeException runtEx;

    private abstract class MySender implements Runnable {
        public MySender() {
            if (Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()) {
                run2();
            } else {
                runtEx = null;
                synchronized(lock) {
                    handler.post(this);
                    try { lock.wait(); } catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
                }
                if (runtEx != null) throw runtEx;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public final void run() {
            try {
                run2();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                runtEx = e;
            }
            synchronized(lock) {
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
        public abstract void run2();
    }
```

Maybe I could use `Future.get()` instead of calling `wait()` myself

Comment: How about Handlers `postDelayed` method?

Comment: does PlayerInterface  used in asynctask?

Comment: The current implementation of PlayerInterface is used in AsyncTask. I want to wrap it with Synchronizer

Comment: does postDelayed() wait?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: But it doesn't wait too

Comment: @Shivam http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996885/how-to-wait-for-android-runonuithread-to-be-finished

Answer (score 0):

With AsyncTask.execute().get() you will wait until the doInBackground() is ended.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: that you can create a thread for the send() so you can call it from your UI thread